# How to add non-touchable view with WindowManager

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I'm trying to add a non-clickable view, which will pass all clicks through it. I'm using the next code

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

But it doesn't works and I still can't find the correct combination. Could anyone please provide correct solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What kind of view is this? Does it have children? If yes, do you want them clickable?

Comment: It's a simple information view, like a toast. But it must pass all clicks through  to system ui.